# Exception while trying using UITabBarController with UITableViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I'm newbie. I'm trying to use UITabBarController with UITableViewController (without UINavigationController), but I've faced with exception after modifying std tabbar project

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController
>   loadView] loaded the "IHHideView" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

My didFinishLaunching

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *hideViewController = [[IHHideViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *unhideViewController = [[IHUnhideViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *filesVIewController = [[IHFilesViewController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[hideViewController,unhideViewController,filesVIewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

IHHideViewController just simplesubclass of UITableViewController

```
@interface IHHideViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

As I know UITableViewController create own UITableView object with the correct dimensions and autoresize mask if not to specify nib file. Why such exception occurs?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are sub-classing a TableViewController. Instead change:

```
@interface IHHideViewController : UITableViewController
```

to:

```
@interface IHHideViewController : UIViewController
```

Comment: Hm... without TabBarController subclassing  UITableViewController works as I expect (without exception)...

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm recreating project using empty template solve problem.